# Problem with installing mcrypt on PHP 7.3.13 Ubuntu

Tags: magento2, php, ubuntu, mcrypt

I have moved my magento 2 project from one vps server to another. So im currently setting up all the PHP modules. But there seem to be some problem with the mcrypt module.

This is what I have been doing.

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
$ sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-de
$ sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2
> libmcrypt prefix? [autodetect] :
```

Im adding "extension=mcrypt.so" to php.ini

Then I do

```
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini"
sudo bash -c "echo extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/mcrypt.so > /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini"
```

I followed these instruction: https://lukasmestan.com/install-mcrypt-extension-in-php7-2/

But when I check with `php -i | grep mcrypt`

I get this is my output:

P

```
HP Warning:  PHP Startup: mcrypt: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20190902
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php/7.3/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini
```

I have checked both 20-mcrypt.ini and mcrypt.ini and they look exaclty the same. But my PHP seems to be compiled with the wrong module API. I google around but couldn't find anything specific on that. Any idéas? Thanks!

What I have been using

- https://websiteforstudents.com/install-php-7-2-mcrypt-module-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48275494/issue-in-installing-php7-2-mcrypt
- https://gist.github.com/arzzen/1209aa4a430bd95db3090a3399e6c35f
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354696/howto-ubuntu-18-04-install-activate-php-extension-ext-mcrypt

Answer (score 1):

Mcrypt is [deprecated since PHP 7.1.x](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php#migration71.deprecated.ext-mcrypt) and is removed now.  I suggest replacing it with libsodium instead. Magento2 integrates without issues.